# Failing monodevelop build because the needed assets seem to be in use... by itself?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I'm facing troubles building MonoDevelop on windows.

All prerequisite steps have been taken:

GitHub, Visual Studio, GTK#, GNU Gettext, Mono Libs and .Net Framework exist or have been installed.

I'm executing the winbuild batch file:

```
winbuild.bat
```

and it runs straight into a wall...
[Warnings/Errors](https://pastebin.com/W46uxiX4)

My intend is to write a half managed and half unmanaged plugin for Unity projects to use, as described [here](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/). I thought it'd be the 'easiest' solution to go with Mono's own IDE for the C# part...

Comment: "I thought it'd be the 'easiest' solution to go with Mono's own IDE for the C# part" is completely wrong. Any C# IDE is better than the broken MonoDevelop on Windows right now.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But I have no idea how to configure VS to accept a Mono Target Framework... I saw that solution with the registry hacks but that'd be last resort for me. I know that there are considerable differences between mono c# and ACTUAL c#. which means it has to be built against that framework, otherwise I'd be missing enum entries that I need to get a mixed dll to work... How to get the native built-in is well documented, just not how to download the broken editor, ironically

Comment: Mono has no special profile itself. Your projects should target .NET Framework 4.x profiles, which are supported by Mono.